# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in angularjs code

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run the example code given in Dave Wahlin's 60ish minutes of AngularJS but getting an error.

The error message is not very easy to understand.

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function SimpleController($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [
                    {name: 'Dave', city: 'Phoenix'},
                    {name: 'Carol', city: 'Los Angeles'},
                    {name: 'Steve', city: 'Seattle'}
                ];
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <div class="container" >
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
            <ul >
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers| filter:name">{{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason stackoverflow is not allowing the angularjs script I have which points to the CDN. Also, there is a body tag outside the div where i have placed ng-controller = "SimpleController"

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the tutorial you're following (which could be outdated), but this simple example runs like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [
        { name: 'Dave', city: 'Phoenix' },
        { name: 'Carol', city: 'Los Angeles' },
        { name: 'Steve', city: 'Seattle' }
       ];
}]);
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/47MQDKbTJKCh2iXE7QTn